# Does jCarousel library work with only images?

Tags: javascript, jcarousel

I am having a hard time putting jCarousel to work with more than images. Has anyome been able to make it work with other tags? (a and span)

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/

Answer (score 0):

What is your exact question? I have implemented various carousels in the past. 
Look for example at the carousel over [here](http://www.epilepsiefonds.nl/) at the bottom right.

Comment: My question was if it was possible to use the jCarousel and put text in it. I can see in your example that it is, but I had already done it. My problem was that I had a thumbnail using several div tags and we cannot use div tags inside li... I just remade the thumbnail to use only a tags a and span. Thanks anyway.